# What is the relationship between 1/7, 1/11, 1/13, and the number 1001?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Here is what we have:

```
 1/7 = 0.142857...
1/11 = 0.090909...
1/13 = 0.076923...
```

Notice that if you add the first three digits to the next three digits, you always get 999:

```
142 + 857 = 999
090 + 909 = 999
076 + 923 = 999
```

Oddly, the same thing happens with `2/7`, `2/11`, `2/13`, and so on, as the numerator increases: adding the first three digits to the next three digit results in 999.

OK. Multiplying the denominators 7 x 11 x 13 results in 1001.

What is the relationship between the fraction series `x/7, x/11, x/13`, and the result of multiplying the denominators?

*<sub>(This is taken from an example in the book ["Ten Ways to Destroy the Imagination of Your Child" by Anthony Esolen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1610170792). The examples above are presented separately, and the reader is encouraged to be imaginative in discovering how they are related. After almost 20 years of playing math/CS games, I suppose I still have no imagination to solve this kind of thing.)</sub>*

Comment: Hint: $\;1001 \cdot 1/7 = (1 + 1000)\cdot 1/7 = 0.\overline{142 857} + 142.\overline{857 142} = \color{red}{142.\overline{142 857 + 857 142}}\,$. On the other hand $1000 \cdot 1/7 = 143 = \color{red}{142.\overline{9}}\,$.

Comment: I propose to call it $\underline{Scheherazade \text{ }Phenomenon}$...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The relationship is that $\frac17=\frac{11\times13}{1001}$, $\frac1{11}=\frac{7\times13}{1001}$ and $\frac1{13}=\frac{7\times11}{1001}$, and the pattern of adding three digits to the next three digits to get $999$ works for any fraction $\frac{n}{1001}$ (apart from the ones that are integers, like $\frac{1001}{1001}$ or $\frac{2002}{1001}$) and for no other number.

Let's see what multiplying *any* number by $1001$ does. We have
$$
1001x=(1000+1)x=1000x+x
$$
So multiplying a number $x$ by $1001$ is the same as taking two copies of $x$, multiply one of them by $1000$ (which has the effect of moving all the digits of $x$ three places to the left), then add them together.

Now, what's special about the numbers $\frac n{1001}$ (again, apart from the ones which are already integers) is that they are the only numbers which are not integers, but multiplying them by $1001$ *makes* them integers. If we use the above interpretation of multiplying by $1001$, the only way that can happen is if after doing the addition, we're left with something with decimal part $.999999\ldots$ (you can try to find examples which make it $.000000\ldots$, but you will not succeed). This means exactly that any three digits of the decimal expansion of $\frac n{1001}$, plus the next three digits must add up to $999$.

(They could, conceivably, add up to $1998$, and let the $1$ carry into the next set of three, but since $1998=999+999$, that means that we would have to start with $.999999\ldots$ already, meaning what we have is an integer. And we're not considering those.)

Comment: A corresponding pattern holds true for any denominator of the form $10^k+1$ with $k\geq1$: for $\frac n{11}$, one digit plus the next is $9$. For $\frac n{101}$, two digits plus the next two gives $99$. And so on. You may also find it intriguing to study the expansions of fractions with denominators $10^k-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing how this phenomenon came to happen (e.g. as explained in Arthurs answer), you can construct similar ones. E.g. You can factor

$$10^\color{red}4+1=73\times 137.$$

You will observe that subdividing the decimal digits of the reciprocals of these factors into blocks of length $\color{red}{\text{four}}$ will give you sums of $9,\!999$:

\begin{align}
1/73& = 0.\underline{0136}\overline{9863}\underline{0136}\overline{9863}...\\[1ex]
1/137 &= 0.\underline{0072}\overline{9927}\underline{0072}\overline{9927}...
\end{align}

---

Further, $1/7$, $1/11$ and $1/13$ also are special for other block lengths: e.g. they give the sum $999,\!999,\!999$ when using block length $\color{blue}{\text{nine}}$ (not *very* surprising). However, there are other such numbers: $1/19$ and $1/52579$. The reason is that

$$10^\color{blue}9+1=7\times 11\times 13\times 19\times 52579.$$

Comment: Oh wow. This compliments Arthur's answer so well! While his answer makes sense to me, I have had trouble applying his explanation to the general situation, so that I could construct *(or discover)* similar patterns in other number sets (and until I can do that, I can't really say that I understand the phenomenon). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(I). A number $R$ between  $0$ and $1$ is represented decimally as   $0.ABCDEFABCDEF...$ iff $10^6R$ is represented as $ABCDEF. ABCDEFABCDEF...$ Subtracting, we see that  $(10^6-1)R$ is represented as $ABCDEF.$

(II). The digit-sequence $ABC$ represents the number $X=10^2A+10B +C$ and the digit-sequence $DEF$ represents the number $Y=10^2D+10E+F .$  Now  $Y=999-X$ iff the digit-sequence $ABCDEF$ represents $(1000 X)+(999-X)=(999)(1+X). $

(III). Combining (I) and (II) we see that $X+Y=999$ iff $ (10^6-1)R=(999)(1+X)$ iff $(999)(1001)R=(999)(1+X)$ iff  $$R=\frac {1+X}{1001}=\frac {1+X}{(7)(11)(13)}.$$

Now $1+X=1+(10^2A+10B+C)$ can be any integer from $1$ to $1000.$ For example if $X=285$ then $(1+X)/1001=286/1001=2/7.$ Or if $X=64$ then $(1+X)/1001=65/1001=5/77.$